# Periodically switch tab in shinydashboard

Tags: r, shiny

In a `shinydashboard` with several tabs like here

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Sample Shiny"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1"),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        "tab1",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Foo")
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        "tab2",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Bar")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

is it possible to let the application switch the active tab periodically? I want to have the dashboard on my screen with switching the active tab every x minutes.

I already checked the Shiny docs for a solution but haven't found an appropriate function. But maybe I simply overlooked such a feature. If Shiny does not offer a suitable feature, is it possible to include some custom JavaScript that does the job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a way to do it, using invalidateLater and updateTabItems:

app.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Sample Shiny"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      id = 'tabs',
      menuItem("Tab 1", tabName = "tab1"),
      menuItem("Tab 2", tabName = "tab2")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        "tab1",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Foo")
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        "tab2",
        fluidRow(
          box(title = "Bar")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

tabnames = c('tab1', 'tab2')
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #keep track of active tab
  active <- reactiveValues(tab = 1)

  observe({
    #Change every 5 secs, you can set this to whatever you want
    invalidateLater(5000,session)
    #update tab
    isolate(active$tab <- active$tab%%length(tabnames) + 1)
    updateTabItems(session,'tabs',tabnames[active$tab])
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks, that totally does the job!